# On the simply connectedness of Symmetric products and Hilbert schemes of points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

My first question is whether $m$-th symmetric product of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is simply connected, where $n\geq 3$.

The second question is whether $Hilb^{m}(\mathbb{C}^{n})$ is simply connected, where $n\geq 3$.

If not, how about the case when $m\gg1$.

Comment: For the first one: it's closed under dilation, so contractible.

Comment: If $Hilb^m(C^n)$ the Hilbert scheme of points?

Answer (score 1):

Re your first question:  If $\pi_1(X)=H_1(X,{\mathbb Z})=0$, then any $m$-th symmetric product of $X$ is simply connected; this is a special case of Theorem 1.1 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.1507.pdf) by Kallel and Taamallah.